# Command Prompt Flickers After Being Opened

Tags: windows, batch-file

After running my .bat, it only flickers and doesn't do the action I want it to do, it just says:

```
C:\test>[a blocky thing]@
'[block]@' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The file is suppose to do a Shutdown, but with a message pop-up in Command Prompt. The script(a bit childish in my opinion):

```
@echo off

title AHHHHH!!!
color a
echo Intruder Alert, Intruder Alert!!! PANIC! Press ALL the buttons!!!
timeout /t 10 /nobreak >nul
CLS
color 4
echo Computer shutdown in 10
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
ClS
color c
echo Computer shutdown in 9
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
ClS
color e
echo Computer shutdown in 8
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
CLS
color 2
echo Computer shutdown in 7
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
CLS
color a
echo Computer shutdown in 6
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
CLS
color 1
echo Computer shutdown in 5
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
CLS
color 9
echo Computer shutdown in 4
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
CLS
color 5
echo Computer shutdown in 3
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
CLS
color d
echo Computer shutdown in 2
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
CLS
color f
echo Computer shutdown in 1
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
CLS
color a
echo.>"C:\test\OpenMe.vbs"

(echo Hi...) > C:\test\OpenMe.vbs

echo Initializing Shutdown Sequence...
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
CLS
echo Deleting files...
echo:
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul

shutdown -s -t 45 /c  Your computer has died.
```

Picture of Problem(link):
http://s1383.photobucket.com/user/reabeafUser2123/media/Problm_zpsituga1nm.png.html?sort=3&o=0

Comment: Run cmd, drag your bat file to it, press Enter.

Comment: @SomethingDark: Yes, you're correct. It's different than I (thought I) remembered. Thanks.

Comment: With the above error, it should just exit.

Comment: @Brogan I want the .bat file to run automatically after being double clicked.

Comment: @user2123 If you're double clicking a bat file, the command prompt window won't stay open once its done doing whatever it does. Thats why it "only flickers". You're not getting a chance to see what might be going wrong. Open it directly in cmd until you know it works.

Comment: @Brogan The problem with the file is that, CMD runs it and it cannot run the first line(@echo off). It interprets it as a more of a vertical rectangle, followed by @.

Comment: @user2123 Which text editor are you using to edit your .bat file? If you're seeing funny characters, you might be using a text editor thats saving your file in a unicode format or possibly something different where batch files only support ANSI encoding. If you're using Notepad++, use the Encoding menu at the top to switch it to ANSI. If you're using regular Notepad, you may be able to switch the encoding when selecting the Save location.

Comment: @Brogan I'm using Notepad on Windows 7. Also, I added a picture link that shows my problem at the top.

Comment: Dude, grab yourself a copy of Notepad++ or a hex editor like xvi32 or something and remove the header bytes. You're not saving in ANSI.

Comment: @Brogan Is it possible to save in ANSI using just Notepad?